# Backbone model, add global attribute which will be there on every instance of the model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

How do I set a property to my backbone model and keep it "globally" in every instance of the model.

```
var myModel = new MyModel();

myModel.set('test', 1234);
```

And now, in **another view**, I instantiate the model again:

```
var myModel = new MyModel();

myModel.get('test')
```

Should return 1234, not null.

Any ideas on how to do it?

I need this because I fetch a token from my rest api and I want to pass it to every request.

So, after I do `myModel.fetch()`, I would like to add the value of the token, bind it to the model, so I'll have it in all my future requests.

Edit, here is the actual code:

```
var proxy = new Proxy(),

                    target = '?csurl=http://laravelws.dev/account/token';

                proxy.urlRoot = proxy.urlRoot + target;

                proxy.fetch(
                    {
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success : function (resp) {
                            that.token = resp.get('_token');
                            proxy.set('_token', that.token);
                        }, 
                        error : function (model, xhr, options) {
                            console.log('router.js - could not fetch the CSRF token');
                        }
                    }
                );
```

I want to atach the token to the proxy model, and make the token available for all the future instances of the model.

This code goes into the router's initialize function - so this get request will be made every time someone lands on my app, or refreshes the page.

Comment: I think you could put `this.set('test', 1234)` in `MyModel`'s `.initialize`.

Comment: I need to do it outside the model, let me update the code, to see more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use defaults:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    test: 1234
  }
});
```

Edit:

To achieve what you're looking for, you could set the value on the prototype:

```
Proxy.prototype.token = "XXX";

var proxy = new Proxy();
console.log(proxy.token);
```

Just be aware that the `token` value will be shared (if you change the value, it changes for *all* proxy instances).

Comment: Yes, but I don't have the value until the ajax is made, I need to bind it to the mode, after I have the value of the token

Comment: Updated my answer... Note: you should also be able to do `Prox.defaults.token = "XXX"`, but the token value won't be udpated for existing instances (whereas it will iff you add it to the prototype).

Comment: Ty David, will test it and approve the answer... I believe the prototype method is better since the token is the same for the whole php session, and I;'ll be updating it inside the router - which is the entry point of my app.